# Concise way to get object keys including keys from prototype chain

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get all keys of given object. Currently I am using `for in` loop.

```
class A {
  static a = 'a';
}

class B extends A {
  static b = 'b';
}

const keys = [];
for (const key in B) {
  keys.push(key);
}

console.log(keys); // ["b", "a"]
```

Is there any way to do it in more concise way e.g. something like `Object.keys` method but including keys from prototype chain?

Comment: `for..in` will only give you the enumerable keys. Is that what you want, or dou you want ALL keys?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is negative. None of the new ES6+ native `Object` methods does traverse the prototype chain, AFAIK.

Comment: @Thomas enumerable would be sufficient